# Using mysql database table authenticated multiple site user / SSO

Tags: mysql, yii, single-sign-on, openid, moodle

I have implement SOS concept between two php application. it application it available different domain.

I have required following condition.

1.When user is login any appplication to login this user with check user name and password into mysql database table

2.When user is login another application not reenter password direct login with this system.

3.When user logout at time both application can be logout.

-->my first application can be created Yii framework and another is moodle

please give idea to implement this concept in my both application

Answer (score 0):

You can use external database authentication for Moodle -

https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/External_database_authentication

Log into Moodle as an admin then go to site admin -> plugins -> authentication -> manage authentication.

Enable the "external database plugin" and then update the settings to use the external database and map the fields for username, password, email etc.

Comment: Your answer is right but when user is login first application then user can login second application at that time user re enter username and password. I have achieve single sign on similar to Google when user is log in any application after the user is not enter any username/password

Comment: You could try a different authentication plugin - https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Authentication - although we use simplesaml which saves a token, it can be used with Facebook, Twitter and Openid - https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?id=100